# ошибка 'document is not defined. [no - undef]'

Tags: jquery

И снова здравствуйте всем! Пытаюсь подключить плагин, чтобы на сайте была возможность включить версию для слабовидящих. Выскакивает критическая ошибка 'document is not defined. [no - undef]', что может быть не так? спасибо заранее

```js
(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.bvi-panel-open').bvi('Init', {
    "BviPanel": "1",
    "BviPanelBg": "white",
    "BviPanelFontSize": "12",
    "BviPanelLetterSpacing": "normal",
    "BviPanelLineHeight": "normal",
    "BviPanelImg": "1",
    "BviPanelImgXY": "1",
    "BviPanelReload": "0",
    "BviCloseClassAndId": ".hide-screen-fixed",
    "BviFixPanel": "1",
    "BviPlay": "1"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начнем с HTML: ( Удалил странные скрипты в конце, потому что мешали мне, можете вернуть их обратно. )  Все должно работать!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Сайт учителя-логопеда Будаевой Людмилы Владимировны</title>     
<link href="button-visually-impaired-jquery/button-visually-impaired/css/bvi.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    
</head>
    <style> 

      body {
        background: url(images/fon4.jpg);
        background-position: center center; /*Задает начальное положение фонового изображения, установленного с помощью свойства background-image.*/
        background-repeat: no-repeat; /*Определяет, как будет повторяться фоновое изображение, установленное с помощью свойства background-image. Можно установить повторение рисунка только по горизонтали, по вертикали или в обе стороны. */
        background-attachment: fixed; /*Свойство background-attachment устанавливает, будет ли прокручиваться фоновое изображение вместе с содержимым элемента. Изображение может быть зафиксировано и оставаться неподвижным, либо перемещаться совместно с документом*/
        background-size: cover; /*Масштабирует фоновое изображение согласно заданным размерам.*/
      }
      header {
        display: block;
      }
      .header-bg {
        background: url(images/fon13.png) no-repeat center bottom; 
                /* Животные */
        height: 300px; /* Высота шапки */
        text-align: center; /* Выравнивание по центру */
      }
       .header-bg img {
        position: relative; /* Относительное позиционирование */
        top: 40px; /* Сдвигаем картинку вниз */
       }
</style>
  <body>







   <div class="header-bg">

   </div>

   <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="background-color: bisque">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">ОБЩИЕ СВЕДЕНИЯ</a></li>
        <li><a href="normi.html">НОРМЫ РЕЧЕВОГО РАЗВИТИЯ</a></li>
          <li><a href="rech.html">НАРУШЕНИЯ РЕЧИ</a></li>
          <li><a href="spec.html">КОГДА ОБРАТИТЬСЯ К СПЕЦИАЛИСТУ</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">АРТИКУЛЯЦИОННАЯ И ДЫХАТЕЛЬНАЯ ГИМНАСТИКА <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li style="background-color: bisque"><a href="agym.html">АРТИКУЛЯЦИОННАЯ ГИМНАСТИКА</a></li>
            <li style="background-color: bisque"><a href="dgym.html">ДЫХАТЕЛЬНАЯ ГИМНАСТИКА</a></li>



          </ul>
        </li>

          <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">МОИ РАБОТЫ <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li style="background-color: bisque"><a href="rrabota.html">РАБОТА С РОДИТЕЛЯМИ</a></li>
            <li style="background-color: bisque"><a href="prabota.html">РАБОТА С ПЕДАГОГАМИ</a></li>



          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="НАЙТИ ЧТО НИБУДЬ">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">ПОИСК</button>
      </form>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>


            <a href="#" class="bvi-panel-open">Версия для слабовидящих</a> 

            <li><a href="#" class="bvi-panel-open-menu">Версия для слабовидящих</a></li>


         <p class="test"><img src="images/mama1.jpg" align="left" hspace="5" vspace="5"></p> 
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p id="test2"><big><big>Уважаемые педагоги и родители! 
Всех посетителей сайта  приветсвует 
учитель-логопед Будаева Людмила Владимировна! </big></big></p></div>

        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <ul class="test1">
        <li><b>Уровень образования</b> - высшее.МГГУ им. М А Шолохова, специальность "Логопедия" </li>
            <li><b>Квалификация</b>: учитель-логопед.</li>
            <li><b>Общий стаж работы</b>: 30 лет.</li>
            <li><b>Стаж работы по специальности</b>: 30 лет</li>
            <li><b>Данные о повышении квалификации и профессиональной переподготовке</b>: 
                <b>2013г</b> - обучение по модульным программам повышение квалификации для специалистов образовательных учреждений и психолого-педагогических комиссий- логопедов, психологов, социальных педагогов, дефектологов, обеспечивающих распространение организованно правовых моделей успешной социализации детей с ОВЗ и детей-инвалидов, на базе стажировочных площадок, Минобразования и науки РФ, Научно-образовательный центр "Социальная защита детей и молодежи" МГГУ им. М.А.Шолохова, 40ч.
                <b>2015 год</b> - БОУ ДПО (ПК)С " Чувашский республиканский институт образования" Минобразования и молодежной политики ЧР по теме: " Профессиональная компетентность учителя-логопеда в рамках требований ФГОС", удостоверение, 72ч.</li>
            <li><b>Награды</b>: Почетная грамота управления образования администрации г.Чебоксары, 2013.</li>
        </ul>
        </div>


    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/dip1-23.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>







</div>


        <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/dip4-1.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

             <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/dip2-4.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

             <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/dip3-7.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


             <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/dip5-6.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/dip6-5.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/dip7-2.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/dip8-3.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/2-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/3-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/4-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/5-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/6-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/7-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/8-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/9-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  

             <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/10-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  

        </div>


         <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/11-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/12-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="background: rgba(238,28,36,0)">
      <img src="images/Diploms/13-1001.jpg" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


        </div>

            <div class="scrollup">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i>
                <a href="#" id="up">наверх</a>
            </div>




    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>    
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="button-visually-impaired/js/responsivevoice.min.js"></script>
    <script src="button-visually-impaired/js/bvi-init-panel.js"></script>
    <script src="button-visually-impaired/js/bvi.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="button-visually-impaired/js/js.cookie.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src='button-visually-impaired-jquery/button-visually-impaired/js/responsivevoice.min.js?ver=1.5.0'></script>  -->
    <!-- <script src="button-visually-impaired-jquery/button-visually-impaired/js/bvi-init-panel.js"></script>  -->
    <!-- <script src="button-visually-impaired-jquery/button-visually-impaired/js/bvi.min.js"></script>  -->
    <script src="button-visually-impaired-jquery/button-visually-impaired/js/js.cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Если это jQuery - то вы должны написать `(jQuery)` или `$` перед `(document)`

```
    // A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.bvi-panel-open').bvi('Init', {
    "BviPanel": "1",
    "BviPanelBg": "white",
    "BviPanelFontSize": "12",
    "BviPanelLetterSpacing": "normal",
    "BviPanelLineHeight": "normal",
    "BviPanelImg": "1",
    "BviPanelImgXY": "1",
    "BviPanelReload": "0",
    "BviCloseClassAndId": ".hide-screen-fixed",
    "BviFixPanel": "1",
    "BviPlay": "1"
  });
});
```

Comment: да, jQuery, попробовал и (jQuery), и $ перед (document) поставить, пишет еще теперь '(jQuery) is not defined. [no - undef]', либо $ is not defined соотвественно если ставить $

Comment: Вы убрали event из функции ‘$’? Покажите как у вас подключены script

Comment: а каким образом можно показать это здесь? извините если что, не разобрался до конца с взаимодействием с сайтом, могу так 
'<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>'

Comment: и на счет event убран или нет, не совсем понимаю про что Вы, дубовые знания jQuery, да и скрипт не мой

Comment: Редактируйте вопрос по ссылке ‘править’ .  Добавьте html разметку. Касательно ‘event’ - ‘function(event){}’

Comment: а вообще лучше `codepen` создать просто pen и кинуть ссылку из этой песочницы, что бы быстро редактировать ваш код и найти ошибку.

Comment: https://codepen.io/NoJokeBro/pen/LgQOPe

Comment: просто ссылка с сайта подойдет?

Comment: @Pavlik да, только вы указали там скрипты, расположенные у вас на desktop, нужно cdn для песочницы найти, сейчас, секунду

Comment: Так, у вас явная проблема со ссылками и подключениями, сейчас исправлю все.

Comment: понимаю, это в любом случае, туго с адаптацией чужого, не факт что правильного под свое

Comment: @Pavlik у вас проблемы со структурой построения html - советую более тщательно изучить азы. У вас тэги повторяются, много отступов, не в том порядке подключены стили и так далее.

Comment: это тоже скорее всего правда

Comment: @Pavlik Все, исправил ответ, посмотрите, советую настоятельно изучить для начала правила построения HTML а потом переходить на JS

Comment: Так же проверьте пути по которым вы подключаете все!

Comment: понял, будем изучать, спасибо

Comment: а в самом скрипте нужно что то добавить или исправить? ваш вариант html заменил, вроде бы все так же осталось

Comment: Ознакомьтесь подробнее ‘http://bvi.isvek.ru/install-jquery/‘

Comment: читал перед тем как добавлять что то, чего то недопонимаю видимо